# How do I evaluate specific samples from a simple random sample (SRS)?

Tags: statistics

I am asked to do the following: "Generate a SRS of size $n$ for the population $X\sim N(2,3^2)$, and evaluate the samples of $\frac{\overline{X}-2}{\sqrt{3^2/n}}$, $\frac{(n-1)S^2}{3^2}$, and $(\frac{\overline{X}-2}{\sqrt{3^2/n}}, \frac{(n-1)S^2}{3^2})$, respectively. Then, based on the corresponding samples, plot estimated density curves of $\frac{\overline{X}-2}{\sqrt{3^2/n}}$ and $\frac{(n-1)S^2}{3^2}$, respectively, and also make the scatter plot of $(\frac{\overline{X}-2}{\sqrt{3^2/n}}, \frac{(n-1)S^2}{3^2})$".

Then, for four different values of $n,$ I must simulate "$\frac{\overline{X} -2}{\sqrt{3^2/n}}$ and $\frac{(n-1)S^2}{3^2}$ for 100 times".

I am very confused about what the task at hand is. I'm using R to do this, but I think my issue here is with the math not with the code. I understand what an SRS is, what the normal distribution is, and what a density curve is. But what does it mean to evaluate these specific samples for 100 times or to plot them against each other? My hunch is that the first sample has something to do with a t-distribution and the second with a chi squared distribution just on the format in which they are given. Beyond that, I am lost.

Thank you for any help! And if this is the wrong place to ask questions like this, please ignore or feel free to remove.

Comment: The distribution of $\Big(\frac{\overline{X}-2}{\sqrt{3^2/n}}, \frac{(n-1)S^2}{3^2}\Big)$ should be that the first component is distributed as $\operatorname N(0,1)$ and the second as $\chi^2_{n-1},$ but also that the two components are independent. Your scatterplots should on average show zero correlation. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

Here is R code, which I hope is transparent, to get you started.

```
set.seed(2020)
mu = 2; sg = 3;  n = 10;  m = 10^5
x = rnorm(m*n, mu, sg)
MAT = matrix(x, nrow=m)   # 10,000 by 10 matrix
a = rowMeans(MAT)         # 10,000 sample averages
s = apply(MAT, 1, sd)     # 10,000 sample SDs
z = (a-mu)/(3/sqrt(n))    #   stamdard normal RVs
```

Descriptive statistics are consistent with population mean 0
and population SD 1 of standard normal

```
summary(z);  sd(z)
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
-4.555486 -0.673631  0.003045  0.001710  0.676686  4.410724 
[1] 0.9971799
```

Descriptive statistics are consistent with population mean 9
and population variance 18 of $Q \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(\nu=9).$

```
q = (n-1)*s^2/(sg^2)     # CHISQ(9) random variables
summary(q);  var(q)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  0.460   5.896   8.323   8.990  11.385  42.717 
[1] 18.06478
```

For normal data (only) sample means and sample variances (SDs)
are independent. The correlation $r \approx 0$ is consistent
with population correlation $\rho = 0.$

```
cor(z, q)
[1] 0.003308312
```

The histograms are consistent with samples from $\mathsf{Norm}(0,1)$ and $\mathsf{Chisq}(9),$ respectively. The scatterplot
is consistent with independent $A = \bar X$ and $Q.$

[image]

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
 hist(z, prob=T, col="skyblue2", 
      main="Sim Dist'n Z ~ NORM(0,1)")
  curve(dnorm(x), add=T, col="red", lwd=2)
 hist(q, prob=T, col="skyblue2", 
      main="Sim Dist'n Q ~ CHISQ(9)")
  curve(dchisq(x,n-1), add=T, col="red", lwd=2)
 plot(z,q, pch=".", main="Scatterplot: (Z, Q)")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

---

*Addendum:* Sample means and SDs are independent only
for normal data. For exponential data, we see high correlation. For data from $\mathsf{Beta}(.1,.1),$
mean and SD are uncorrelated by symmetry, but the
scatterplot shows they are not independent.

```
set.seed(2020)
n = 10;  m = 50000
w = rexp(m*n)
MAT = matrix(w, nrow=m)   # samples from EXP(1)
a.w = rowMeans(MAT)         
s.w = apply(MAT, 1, sd)
cor(a.w, s.w)     
[1] 0.7639301             # r not 0

v = rbeta(m*n, .1, .1)
MAT = matrix(v, nrow=m)   # samples from BETA(.1,.1)
a.v = rowMeans(MAT)         
s.v = apply(MAT, 1, sd)
cor(a.v, s.v)  
[1] 0.009162465           # r consistent with 0
```

[image]

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
 plot(a.w, s.w, pch="'", 
      main="EXP: Sample Mean and SD Correlated")
 plot(a.v, s.v, pch="'", 
      main="BETA: Sample Mean and SD, r=0, Dependent")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```